# JAX-RS response producing escaped JSON for a string

Tags: json, jax-rs

I am using JAX-RS to produce a webservice. For this piece of the web service, I have a JSON string that I need to send to the user, but the problem is that JAX-RS is escaping the String before sending it.  Here is the concrete problem.

The service looks like this:

```
@GET
@Produces("application/json")
public String serializeConfiguration() {
    return exportConfiguration();
}
```

User goes to http://mycompany.com/export-configuration

User wants a response of:

```
{
  "myconfig" : "some stuff"
}
```

but instead gets:

```
"{\n      \"myconfig\" : \"some stuff\"\n    }"
```

What is going on here is obviously that the string is being escaped. Instead, I want the raw string, but keeping the same content type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have JSON as String it should work if you create a Response with this entity:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response config() {
    return Response.ok(exportConfiguration()).build();
}
```

Comment: I'll accept this answer since it is technically correct. It didn't solve my own problem since we are using a `javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter` that I didn't know about and converts everything to JSON.  My answer was one way to get around it.

Comment: Oh, thanks for this info. Just realized that also returning a JSON-String is working out of the box. So my answer does not make much sense. Maybe it's better you explain the real problem and accept your own answer. I'll delete mine then. Don't know if it's possible for you but you could also try to add another `MessageBodyWriter` which is mapped to a String.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, looks like I need to write to the response object directly.  Like this:

```
@GET
public void serializeConfiguration(@Context HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    response.setStatus(200);
    response.setCharacterEncoding(Charsets.UTF_8.name());
    response.getWriter().write(exportConfiguration());
    response.getWriter().close();
}
```